# Why Android Studio won't format sql statement?

Tags: android, android-studio

```kotlin
@Query(
        """
        SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY
    CASE 
WHEN :order = 1 THEN id END
    """
    )
    fun pagingSource(order: Int): PagingSource<Int, Article>
```

I have the above sql statement code, when I use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` key combination, Android Studio will not format the code of the sql statement.

The code I expect (it may turn out that):

```kotlin
@Query(
        """
        SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN :order = 1 THEN id END
    """
    )
    fun pagingSource(order: Int): PagingSource<Int, Article>
```

The version I am using is: `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit how it behaves in `Preference`->`Editor`-> `Code Style` -> desired language (e.g. `Kotlin`)

Comment: Can you go into more detail? There are many options under the kotlin page.

Comment: You probably want to set `Tab size` and `Indent` params. Play around with them, you have preview there, so you can see the result.

Comment: No, I don't think you understand my question. The indentation you mentioned has actually been implemented in my sample code. You can learn about the `Reformat code` command.

Comment: I do not think you understand my answer :).
Question - How does Android Studio automatically format SQL statements?
Answer - it does how you tell it to, there are just default settings you may change. Where? I gave you an example where.

Comment: My fault, `automatically` may have misunderstood you, I will delete this word now.
I've supplemented my answer by adding the code after the formatting is done (which may not be the case), but I think this should explain that my problem isn't really about the amount of indentation.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I cannot help you more, but indentation is the exact thing you need to fix.
Just curious - Why are you using """ ? instead of "SELECT ..... " ?

Comment: Because the sql statement will be longer in the actual example, if you use `""`, you need to use `+` to connect each row, and I personally don’t like to use `+` to connect.

From a certain point of view, it has to do with indentation, but that is not accurate. Sorry I don't speak English very well, I'm using a machine translated language so I can't tell you exactly the difference. But I think you don't understand `Reformat code` command, am I right?

Comment: You can use `+` with "normal" double quotes. I have just checked it in my project.
I understand the `Reformat code` and I use it million times a day. You can set up reformating where I pointed and adjust it to your needs. I really do not know how to help you, but please, try to play with settings I proposed. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I've set `Tab size` and `Indent` params to 2, like I thought it didn't help. The reason why Android Studio does not reformat is that it does not recognize that this is a sql statement, or it does not support this function, and may need the help of a plug-in.